# angular2 stomp can't receive message from spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I use spring oauth2 and angular2 stateless security .

I can send topic message to angular2 client . But client can't receive the individual message , why?

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pcAngular2");
    }
```

send method:

```
@GetMapping("/front")
    public ResponseEntity s(){

String userId="da94470c-4e9b-4e86-990e-811666861fe6";

        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId,
                "/queue/websocketAndMessage", "hello");

        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }
}
```

angular2 client:

```
const individulaSubUrl = '/user/queue/websocketAndMessage';

this.stompClient.subscribe(xdidianSubUrl, e=> {
          console.log(e.body);
          this.doWithWebsocket(e.body);
        })
```

and the client log:

```
stomp.js:134Opening Web Socket...
lang.js:114Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
X-CSRF-TOKEN:d0168a17-5cfa-4a1a-bdf1-d95cf2940688
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000


stomp.js:134 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0


stomp.js:134 connected to server undefined
stomp.js:134 >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/user/queue/websocketAndMessage
```

> when i get "/front" , that is spring invoke
>   "simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser" method .
>
> but angular2 client didn't receive expected message .